# js an css not works altought break point is set

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

My breakpoint is 1000px and having a class in `<header>`.But my document is neither following any one of the condition.
Here is the prblem with css:

```
body:not(.logged-in) .header-xs {
   top: 0;
   padding-top: 11vh;
}
```

and the problem with js is:

```
jQuery(window).on('load resize', function(){
    if(jQuery(window).width() > 1000 && !jQuery('header').hasClass('header-xs')){
         jQuery('body').css('margin-top', '0');
         jQuery('header').css({'margin-top': 'inherit', 'padding-top' : 'inherit'});
    }
})
```

I am working on wordpress.Here when a person is logged in then the `logged-in` class is added to `<body>`.but i'm working without being logged-in.

And js once it adds `'margin-top': 'inherit'; 'padding-top' : 'inherit'` persists even i resize to mobile width size.

Comment: Regarding your last sentence, the JS shown only changes those CSS properties if the width is more than 1000, it never removes them. You need an `else` case to set/remove them for resizes to less than or equal to 1000.

Comment: you have header and body? your css can't target header. it can only go sibling or child

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying my best to understand your problem, so try this and let me if it is close to what you are trying to do.

Also the css you have, if you try to target a header above body with a class, it won't really work. You might need use js.

```js
jQuery(window).on('load resize', function() {
 console.log('resize - '+jQuery(window).width());
  if (jQuery(window).width() > 1000) {
  jQuery('header').removeClass('header-xs');
    jQuery('body').css('margin-top', '0');
    jQuery('header').css({
      'margin-top': 'inherit',
      'padding-top': 'inherit'
    });
  } else {
  jQuery('header').addClass('header-xs');
 }
})
```

```css
body:not(.logged-in) .header-xs {
  top: 0;
  padding-top: 11vh;
 background: red;
}

body {
 background: green;
}


.header-xs {
 boder: 15px solid blue;
 height: 250px;
 width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header class="header-xs">
</header>
<body>
</body>
```

Comment: about the css: its like : `<body class="classes logged-in"><header class="header-xs"></header>`

Comment: @muhaimin ok, in what case you want remove `header-xs` and what case you need to add this class?